# Selenium Chrome driver click does not work

Tags: c#, selenium

```
 IWebElement  advancedSearchButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("advanced-search"));

 advancedSearchButton.Click();
```

this code works when the click button is displayed in the chrome driver, but when I resize the chrome to a very small size and the button is not displayed on the browser but it is loaded, click action does not work. When I minimize the chrome, click action works I am confused what to do ? I want to eventually try to make chrome as small as possible to hide the detail from the user kind of trying to run headless with windows C# please help thank you

Comment: I would suggest that if your ultimate aim is to run a headless browser, then run a headless browser. Messing with Chrome's size is going to lead to a number of problems you simply won't get when using a headless browser. When it's resized to a small size, is the button still in view to the user?

Comment: I used phantom js but then I cannot debug with PhantomJS do you know any debugger for PhantomJS ?

Comment: why not use a selenium grid? that way you can have dedicated machines running the test for you so you won't even **have** to worry about seeing the window